# ObjectBox: Concurrent Write transactions

Tags: android, objectbox

I watched the [droidcon NYC 2017 speach of ObjectBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vr2sduWaJ4w) and there is one part in which Markus Junginger talks about transactions (around min 25).

The slide in this minute states:

> **No, we do not drop ACID: Transactions FTW!**
>
> - ObjectBox is fully transactional (ACID)
> - Multi Version conurrency
>     *Multi concurrent readers (read TX)
>
>     Single writer (write TX)*
> - implicit transaction
>     *e.g. put(song), put(songList)*

Does *Single writer (write TX)* mean that I cannot have 2 write transactions in parallel?

**[edit]**

I might have found the answer [here](http://objectbox.io/documentation/transactions/#Multiversion_concurrency)

> Write transactions are executed sequentially to ensure a consistent
>   state. Thus, it is advised to keep write transactions short to avoid
>   blocking other pending write transactions.

Still happy for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found the correct documentation. Always one writer at a time. E.g. only a single `runInTx` (or `put` etc.) in progress at any time.

Update: Note that you do not have to worry about making write transactions sequential yourself. If multiple threads want to write at the same time (e.g. via  put or  runInTx), one of the treads will be selected to go first, while the other threads have to wait. It works just like a lock or synchronized in Java.

Comment: Thanks! But the framework will manage this, right? There will never be a weird NoConcurrentWriteTransactionException or something, will there?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I clarified that in the docs and copied it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering! :)

Comment: @MarkusJunginger Consider a scenario where I have 2 threads called Thread1 and Thread2. Thread2 starts reading from the database first and reads the Object having ID of 1. Now it performs the network operation and in that time Thread1 modifies the property name "Delivered" along with 3-4 other properties of Object having ID of 1. After the network operation finishes, Thread2 modifies only the "Delivered" property of the object. In this case, the other properties of the object will remain as modified by Thread1, or it will be replaced with the old state cause Thread2 read from the DB first?

Comment: Depends how you do it. If you want to only want to update a single property (e.g. "delivered"), then you want to get/refresh the object **inside** the write transaction that will put the object.